# In Microsoft SQL Server 2008, syntax generates the error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled."

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, window-functions

I have the following virtual column generated from an aggregate over a sorted partition,

```
MIN(picture_id) OVER ( PARTITION BY [360_set] ORDER BY picture_id ASC )
```

However, when I execute that, I get the following.

```
Msg 11305, Level 15, State 10, Line 12
The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.
```

This is where it gets interesting though, without a sort order on the partition, it works:

```
MIN(picture_id) OVER ( PARTITION BY [360_set] )
```

And, further, `ROW_NUMBER()` a window function (not an aggregate function) works with an explicit order on the partition.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [360_set] ORDER BY picture_id ASC )
```

How come the desired statement doesn't work? Where is this documented? The version information was requested, this is what I in Help → About.

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio          10.0.5512.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools        10.0.5500.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.10.9200.16635
Microsoft .NET Framework                        2.0.50727.5472
Operating System                                6.1.7601
```

The result from `SELECT @@VERSION` is `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5512.0 (X64)   Aug 22 2012 19:25:47   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)`

Comment: What's the exact version? Seems like a bug. I get a normal syntax error for the first example on 10.50.1600. Aside from that, though, I don't see the point -- what are you trying to do with this syntax?

Comment: So do you actually care about partitioning the ranking by `[360_set]`, or is that part irrelevant? Also, from your comment, the formula you gave only works like the text description if there are no gaps in the sequence. Which do you want?

Comment: No, it's highly relevant only when 360_set is set to 1 or 2 do we need the fourth-picture logic, shy of that we want all pictures. I'd rather it work if there were gaps in the sequence... And, you just solved problem. Touché and well done @JonSeigel. Didn't think of just using ROW_NUMBER(). I think I should leave this question open though and keep it fixed on syntax since it should work the other way.

Comment: The order by clause for aggregates wasn't implemented until SQL Server 2012. Not sure what the PDW extensions are.

Comment: @Martin: Can you explain what the `ORDER BY` does in the context of `MIN(...) OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`? This seems nonsensical to me, even though it appears to be valid syntax in 2012.

Comment: You didn't paste version info. You pasted the build of Management Studio. Please replace that with the results of `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: @AaronBertrand my own fault, it's been updated, but the version is the same as the version of the SQL Server Mgmt Studio.

Comment: @JonSeigel It sets the order of rows for the window frame. It does not affect the way `MIN` works of course, but it does change the rows in the frame over which `MIN` is performed.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks, I understood that from the documentation for the general case. I'm just confirming that the *results* of the fragment in my comment would be identical with and without the `ORDER BY`, since `MIN` over a set is the same regardless of the order of the elements in the set. Is that correct, or is there some kind of subtle difference? For aggregate functions, it seems `OVER(ORDER BY)` is only useful when using the new 2012 extensions (`ROW`/`RANGE`).

Comment: @JonSeigel - The default if not specified is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. So the window only includes values with `picture_id` values less than or equal to that in the current row.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> *The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.*

This is a parser bug that exists only in SQL Server 2008. Non-PDW versions of SQL Server before 2012 [do not support the `ORDER BY` clause with aggregate functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) like `MIN`:

[image: Books Online extract]

Windowing function support was considerably extended in 2012, compared with the basic implementation available starting with SQL Server 2005. The extensions were made available in Parallel Data Warehouse before being incorporated in the box product. Because the various editions share a common code-base, misleading error messages like this are possible.

If you are interested, the call stack when the aggregate is verified by the parser is shown below. Because the aggregate has an `OVER` clause with `ORDER BY`, a check for PDW is issued:

[image: Aggregate verification]

This check immediately fails with a parser error:

[image: Parser error]

Luckily, you do not need an windowed aggregate that supports `ORDER BY` framing to solve your code problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a result of the merging of the PDW, Azure and box version's code bases.  We'll start to see messages like this or that you aren't on an Azure machine when trying to do stuff that has only been released in Azure.

As for Martin's question about what the PDW extensions are, these would be the features of the T-SQL language which are only implemented in the Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) product.

Comment: Can these be enabled through a hack? Or, are they not shipped with the product? I'm just wondering if they seriously pulled that rudimentary feature? It's not that complex for DB use.

Comment: @EvanCarroll No, `ORDER BY` with windowed aggregates cannot be enabled in SQL Server 2008. The feature was not 'pulled', it was not released for non-PDW SQL Server until the 2012 release.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this as an element of the error message. As @MartinSmith said above,

> The order by clause for aggregates wasn't implemented until SQL Server 2012. Not sure what the PDW extensions are. – *Martin Smith*

This is mentioned officially here [SQL Server 2008 R2 - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> When used in the context of a ranking window function,  can only refer to columns made available by the FROM clause. An integer cannot be specified to represent the position of the name or alias of a column in the select list.  **cannot be used with aggregate window functions.**

Even more significant is the verbiage in [SQL Server 2012 - OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

> Depending on the ranking, aggregate, or analytic function used with the OVER clause,  and/or the  may not be supported.

So, it looks like it *certainly* is not available in 2008 -- though that error message is a really obscure way of saying *"not implemented"*, and in 2012 it looks like Microsoft's official stance is *your mileage may vary*.